# Dart. What the difference between using generic T and Object?

Tags: generics, dart

I try to understand what the difference between using Generics and Object. I've already read some answers related to Java (please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5207175/1349754) and I found the difference quite noticeable - function/method returns (a) Object if we use Object as input argument type and (b) actual type if we use generic T. However Dart has its own behavior and this case it not applicable. Let's see example:

```
main() {
  // expect Object type
  print((new TestObject()).Pass('string').runtimeType);
  // expect String type
  print((new TestGeneric()).Pass('string').runtimeType);
  // both output String type
}

class TestObject {
  Object Pass(Object element)
    => element;
}

class TestGeneric<T> {
  T Pass(T element)
    => element;
}
```

I don't have good knowledge of using object-oriented ideology. So please, could anybody explain what the difference of using generics instead of Object base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics allows to avoid many declarations when only types change between several classes. In your example the `TestObject` class can be removed and replaced with `TestGeneric<Object>` everywhere `TestObject` appears.

Your expected output for `(new TestObject()).Pass('string').runtimeType` is not correct. `runtimeType` returns the type of the object. Here it is `'string'` that is returned and so `'string'.runtimeType` is `String`.

To know the return type of a method you have to use [mirrors](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:mirrors) at runtime or [analyzer](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/analyzer) at build time.

Comment: Please, could you give some code example where benefit or generics is obviously. I'm still barely see the difference..

Comment: For instance, if you define `a = new TestGeneric<String>()` you will get a warning _The argument type 'int' cannot be assigned to the parameter type 'String'_ if you call `a.Pass(1);`

Comment: Hm, it make sense! I start to get the idea)