# Passing Any Type As A Method Parameter

Tags: java

I am trying to have a method that can take in ANY TYPE as a parameter (Object, int, boolean, ArrayList, etc.). Here is a very simple method to illustrate what it would be trying to do:

```
public void printAnything(Type arg0) {
    System.out.println(arg0);
}
```

And what I am asking is, what would replace `Type` in that method?

Comment: @Trobbins careful. Generics don't support primitive types.

Comment: @Luig You're right, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think `Object` should do the job, as every object is derived from `Object` and every normal type (int, boolean,...) can get autoboxed, so you should also be able to pass them as arguments...

Comment: @Byte Commander So, you're saying, I could pass an `Integer` as opposed to an `int`?

Comment: Yes, of course. And if I remember right, if you can pass an `Integer`, but give an `int`, Java automatically converts it to its object representation, this also works the other way round, depending on what's needed. This is called autoboxing, I think.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza in this case it make no difference due to autoboxing. see my answer.

Comment: @user140547 primitive and autoboxing may work when using `Object` or generic, but it's not the same. This is noted when you pass an array of primitives and an array of the wrapper class. IMO you should not use any of these approaches for supporting primitive types **ever**. If you want/need to support primitive types, you have to (sadly) overload your method properly.

Answer (score 11):

In your specific example, `Object` would fit well because `PrintStream#println(Object obj)` would print the string representation (using `String#valueOf(Object)`).

When you pass a primitive value, it will be automatically boxed into its wrapper type, e.g an `int` would be converted to `java.lang.Integer` which extends `Object`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use both

```
public void printAnything(Object arg0) {
    System.out.println(arg0);
}
```

and

```
public void <T> printAnything(T arg0) {
    System.out.println(arg0);
}
```

*Both* versions can also be called with primitives thanks to auto-boxing.

see also [Java generics T vs Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207115/java-generics-t-vs-object)

Answer (score 2):

The data type you need to accept is `Object`.

Because in Java, everything is derived from it, except the primitive data types like `int`, `float`, `boolean`, etc.
Those however can also be passed if `Object` is required, because Java automatically converts between primitives (e.g. `int`) and their object representation (e.g. `Integer`), depending on which form fits the method prototype. This feature is called autoboxing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object` as a Type. It can autobox int to Integer and so on.
See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Object class is super class for all other. So, you can use it. See also [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).