# Spring webclient using generic return type

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webclient

I have written below code, i want to return a generic type (Class response) in the method call instead of JsonNode. I am getting error in bodyToMono call if i am using a generic type response object. So how to retrive a generic type response using below code.

```
 public JsonNode exchange(WebClient webClient, WebClientRequest requestDetails, Class<V> response) throws IOException {
    if (requestDetails.getHttpMethod() == null) {
        requestDetails.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
    }
    if (requestDetails.getParams() == null) {
        requestDetails.setParams(new HashMap<>());
    }
    JsonNode result = null;
    try {
        result = webClient
                .method(requestDetails.getHttpMethod())
                .uri(requestDetails.getServiceUrl(), requestDetails.getParams())
                .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.setAll(requestDetails.getHeaders()))
                .exchange()
                .flatMap(ClientResponse -> ClientResponse.bodyToMono(JsonNode.class))
                .retryWhen(Retry.any()
                        .fixedBackoff(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                        .retryMax(5))
                .delaySubscription(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .block();
    } catch (WebClientResponseException ex) {
        log.error("WebClientResponseException in Webclient call : ", ex.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Exception in Webclient call : ", ex.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: If you have an interface and its implementations, use `@JsonTypeInfo`. In other cases, just deserialize as `Object.class` (most likely it will be Map<String, Object> map) and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the method declaration. You have put:

```
public JsonNode exchange(.......
```

With this, you are making a method named "exchange" that returns JsonNode object. To return generic object you need to change the declaration:

```
public <YourClassObject> exchange(......
```

To do it, you can use generic Object class:

```
public Object exchange(...
```

But, when call method exchante(), you will need to cast the result.

To avoid this type of problems, you can use T object. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207115/java-generics-t-vs-object), for example.

Comment: I changed method signature like  - >   public <V> V exchange(WebClient webClient, WebClientRequest requestDetails, V responseType) throws IOException but this line in the method giving error - > .flatMap(ClientResponse -> ClientResponse.bodyToMono(responseType.getClass())) // error variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final